# Android 5: Signal 11 crash instead of NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, crash, signals

An Android application, which uses Native Shared libraries (via JNI), runs correctly on Any Android device.
It has a point in code, where a `NullPointerExcetion` might be thrown,
For example:
1. `Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.security.PrivateKey.getFormat()' on a null object reference`
2. `kjava.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`

in Most of the devices and different versions of Android devices, the thrown exception is trapped and handled - and the application continues running.

BUT: on certain Android devices (e.g. Sony Xperia Z3+), the application crashes due to Signal 11 - after the Native Code is initialized and executed (via JNI).
If the `JNI` code was not executed - the `NullPointerException` is thrown and correctly handled.
Once the `JNI` code is executed, the application would crash on Signal 11 instead of getting the Java Exception.

My questions: have some of you experienced that behavior - Process Signal instead of `Java` `Exception`?
Is there a way to avoid that?

Again, please note that the issue was only detected on Android 5 devices!

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @RatilalChopda no. This question doesn't ask how to fix a NullPointer, it asks how to fix a Signal 11 crash that only occurs on some devices.

Comment: Hi,
It appears that the source of the crash lies in a c++ code, which transforms C/C++ runtime signals into Java exceptions - and under 64 bits Android 5, it wrongly causes the application's signal instead of the Java Exception.